# In a VSCode extension, how to get the number of changes made between a branch A and a branch B?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, diff, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension that needs to know how many changes were made between two branches.

Let's say there is a branch A and a branch B. Branch A has a file with 10 lines. In branch B, I modify the same file so now it has 15 lines. I need get the data that show that there is a 5 line difference between the file in branch A and branch B.

In terminal, I can do this by running "git diff branchA branchB --shortstat" which could show something like "1 file changed, 5 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)". But I did some research and apparently I can't read the terminal output when running a command from a VS Code extension.

I searched for the diff command in VS Code API and Source Control API and didn't find a command that can give me this data.

How could I obtain that data?

Edit

Eventually I found a way to make this work. There is this thing called "Asynchronous process creation" in Node that allows you to create child process that can run git commands. Apparently, this is how they solve this problem in the Git and GitLens extensions. This [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#asynchronous-process-creation) is really helpful and shows how you can do it. I have used the spawn method and it worked fine. I have managed to develop the extension I mentioned in the question. You can see its repository in this [link](https://github.com/leo-holanda/changes-counter) and the code using spawn method in this [link](https://github.com/leo-holanda/changes-counter/blob/main/src/extension.ts).

Answer (score 0):

If the native API is not enough, you can, as a workaround, use the [command API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command) to send a git command to the console:

```js
const vscode = require('vscode');

vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence', {
    text: 'git diff branchA branchB --shortstat\n'
});
```

You can then get the log of the active console for the result:

```js
const terminal = vscode.window.activeTerminal;
const processId = terminal.processId;
const process = vscode.window.terminals.find((terminal) => terminal.processId === processId).processId;

process.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Not ideal, but to be tested in order to execute any command you need.

---

The OP proposes an approach based on the child process at [`leo-holanda/changes-counter` `src/extension.ts`](https://github.com/leo-holanda/changes-counter/blob/d6605758c9dc52fc7d0accf330fb1851ce496a68/src/extension.ts).

Comment: Thanks! I tried this solution but the typescript compiler throws this error: "Property 'process' does not exist on type 'Terminal'. Did you mean 'processId'? ts(2551)". There's another property named "state' that could help but I tried the child process approach and it worked. The code can be found here: https://github.com/leo-holanda/changes-counter/blob/main/src/extension.ts

Comment: @LeoHolanda `processId` indeed. Well done on the child process approach: I have edited the answer to reference it.